# How to use dynamic socket url in components?

Tags: sockets, plugins, socket.io, vue.js

How can I use dynamic socket with different urls/namespaces ?

I first tried with *vue-socket.io*.

**main.js**

```
import VueSocketio from 'vue-socket.io';
Vue.use(VueSocketio, 'http://localhost:8091/notification');
```

And that URL I would want to change dynamicly but i didn't find a way to do it.

---

I also tried with *socket.io-client* in a component.

**component:**

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const adminSocket = io('http://localhost:8091/notification');
```

but it just pendidng all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle dynamic sockets in VueJs with [socket.io-client](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client)

Here an example:

**Parent:**

```
<MyComponent server="http://127.0.0.1:8000/"></MyComponent>
<MyComponent server="http://127.0.0.1:8000/namespaced-socket"></MyComponent>
<MyComponent :server="dynamicServer"></MyComponent>

//...

components: {
  MyComponent
},
```

**Child component:**

```
import SocketIO from 'socket.io-client'

//...

export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  data () {
    return {
      socket: null
    }
  },   
  props: {
    server: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },   
  methods: {
    newSocket () {
      let socket = SocketIO(this.$props.server, { origins: 'http://localhost:*/* http://127.0.0.1:*/*' })
      this.socket = socket
      this.socket.on('data', (data) => { // your server emits, ready, data, etc...
        console.log('data')
        // do whatever you want with `data`
      })
    }
  },    
  mounted () {
    this.newSocket()
  }
}
```

In your parent component (or view), you can create a method to add dynamically a child component in the template, with a new socket inside (if the server change dynamically, you should handle it in the child with an other dedicated method like `this.newSocket()`).

It's possible that you can have a problem with the crossorigin, that's why i added `{ origins: 'http://localhost:*/* http://127.0.0.1:*/*' }` (for example).

**Note:**

[vue-socket.io](https://github.com/MetinSeylan/Vue-Socket.io) allows to create only one single instance.

Be sure that is working as well, i personnally use it for some projects.

Comment: Coud you please explain me, for what we need "this.socket"?

Comment: It's not about socket, only a name for using the socket instance through the component (i could use any other names..)

Comment: btw, origins is a server setting

Comment: Yes, you could add a prop to change origins or parse server prop, this is just an simple not-perfect example that works with localhost.